# Check if any meta on the post has value then display content

Tags: post-meta, metabox

I know how to use the conventional get_post_meta, and I usually call it with each field separately. Is there a way to use them all at once? For example, use an if statement to display content if any metabox field  has content. Not specific to one, but any in the post.

I tried searching for this with no success

So far this works but what if we have a lot of more metaboxes, no easy check on all to find value?

```
<?php $meta1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metabox_1', true );
$meta2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metabox_2', true );
if (!empty($meta1) || !empty($meta2)){?>
//do stuff
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: to get all custom fields of a post dynamically, have a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275424/how-to-display-all-posts-custom-fields-dynamically

Comment: I don't want to display them all dynamically, i'd like to check if theres something in any of the fields and if thats the case, show a div with content

Comment: You need to check the individual fields. Posts will always have _some_ meta that would be irrelevant to what you want to display.

Comment: the mentioned code might give you a starting point to automatically get and check all custom fields of your post, instead of typing them manually...

Comment: I have moved past beyond it and used them individually for now, since the project needs to be moving but I'll go back and study/test later